# How to get absolute coordinates after transformation

Tags: java, java-2d

I am drawing Java 2D stuff like this:

```
g2.translate( getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 );
g2.rotate( angle );
g2.draw( new Ellipse2D.Double( -1, -1, 1, 1 ) );
```

Now I want to kow the coordinates of the ellipse on my sceen. Any idea how to get it? So I need the conversion from logical to physical space.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [AffineTransform](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) from the [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object and use the [transform(src, dst)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#transform%28java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D%29) method to go to screen coordinates (you can do this for any point). If you want the path of the ellipse you can use [Ellipse2D.getPathIterator(AffineTransform at)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html#getPathIterator%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) - it returns a [PathIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html).

This example gets the center point of the ellipse on the screen:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");


    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.translate( getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 );
            g2.rotate(Math.PI); // some angle

            Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double( -10, -10, 10, 10 );
            g2.draw(ellipse);

            Point2D c = new Point2D.Double(
                    ellipse.getCenterX(), 
                    ellipse.getCenterY());

            AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
            Point2D screenPoint = at.transform(c, new Point2D.Double());

            System.out.println(screenPoint);
        }
    });

    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Cool. That's a great idea! Works. Thanks. PS: "Point2D screenPoint = at.transform(c, null);" might be a bit better.

Comment: @Jeny Jeppesen: Yepp! Do as you like! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, there are many methods, you dont find them in Ellipse2D however.

You can use its parent RectangularShape, then depending on how accurate you want it to be you can subtract accounting for the curvature.

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html

Comment: I have no idea how this will solve my problem. I just want the absolute coordinates of the box, not of every pixel. So the same parameter but on physical positions not logical.

Comment: You can use methods from the side i linked like this: g2.getCenterX(), g2.getMaxX(). If your surrounding-rectangle has a coordinate-system of e.g. -1 to 1 try to multiply the value those methods give you with the number of pixels your surrounding-rectangle has divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a reference to the ellipse

```
g2.translate( getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 );
g2.rotate( angle );
Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double( -1, -1, 1, 1 );
g2.draw( ellipse );
```

for x `g2.getTransform().getTranslateX() + ellipse.getX()`

and  for y `g2.getTransform().getTranslateY() + ellipse.getY()`

Comment: No thats not the solution. I need the coordinates after the translation of course. Otherwise I just get 1, but correct would be 440x444 or whatever absolute coordinates.

Comment: @Jeny Edited! can you try this?