# Get rectangle position relative to the screen?

Tags: java

I am facing a similar problem to this question however I'm trying to use java: [AS3 - How to find the position of an object relative to the stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027408/as3-how-to-find-the-position-of-an-object-relative-to-the-stage?rq=1)

I'm drawing a rectangle to the screen. I'm using g.translate and g.rotate to scroll and rotate the screen. The x and y variables I am using to position the rectangle therefore do not depict where the rectangle is on the actual screen. Sorry if I haven't explained it well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204365/1759845

Comment: What library are you using? Swing, javafx, SWT, GWT, ....?

Comment: @n247s awt I believe